# SVG ViewBox Breaks Height

Tags: html, css, svg, layout, flexbox

Why does setting the viewbox attribute on the SVG element mess up the height and causes an overflow? How can I prevent that?

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>testa</h1>
  <div class="child">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 40 40">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to prevent the overflow from showing you can add `overflow-y: hidden` to the **.parent** div.

Comment: I would prefer if the svg doesn't take that much space at all and rather scales its content.

Comment: This would happen with an image also, it's not exclusive to SVG and the use of the `viewBox` attribute.

Comment: It does not happen if I set a fixed height for the svg element. However, I want the svg to fill the remaining space of the parent container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're defining height (via `flex-grow: 1;`), you can use absolute positioning to help you fill the height of `.child`.

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.25); // <= for illustrative purposes
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>testa</h1>
  <div class="child">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 40 40">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

I believe there's an [object-fit](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit) solution out there but the browser support might not be what you need it to be.